# Latest number of string with some format

Tags: mysql

I have mysql database like this

```
id | code
1  | bok-1
2  | bok-2
3  | bok-3
4  | inv-1
5  | inv-2
6  | inv-3
```

How do i get latest number of prefix `bok-`?
code which from the example above the result will be `bok-3`

Comment: does your code follows a certain format like xxx-#

Comment: @Boomer yes it is have some prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :

```
select code
from Table1
where code like "bok%"
order by cast(substring(code from 5) as signed) desc
limit 1
```

EDIT :

it now gives bok-11 if there is a bok-11 in the list, as I suppose 11 is greater than 3.

Comment: Fixed... there was a problem with the lexicographic order of strings... Thanks for the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For the code try:

```
select code from table where id in (select max(id) where code like 'bok-%');
```

and for the id only:

```
select max(id) where code like 'bok-%'
```